# Comparing 2 columns group by group in pandas or python

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have a dataset here where i am unsure of how to compare if the groups have similar values. Here is a sample of my dataset

```
type   value
a       1
a       2
a       3
a       4

b       2
b       3
b       4
b       5

c       1
c       3
c       4



d       2
d       3
d       4
```

I want to know which rows are similar, in the sense that all the (values in 1 type) are present in another type. So for example type d has value 2,3,4 and type a has value 1,2,3,4
so this is 'similar' or can be considered the same so i would like it output something that tells me d is similar to A.

Expected output should be like this

```
type   value            similarity
a       1         A is similar to B and D
a       2
a       3
a       4

b       2         b is similar to a and d
b       3
b       4
b       5

c       1         c is similar to a 
c       3
c       4



d       2         d is similar to a and b
d       3
d       4
```

not sure if this can be done in python or pandas but guidance is really appreciated as i'm really lost and not sure where to begain

the output also does not have to be what i just put as an example here, it can just be another csv that tells me which types are similar and

Comment: When do you consider 2 groups are similar because "a" and "b" have differences (1 and 5)?

Comment: @Corralien i would say when there is at least 2 similarities or maybe even 3 in it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use set operations.

##### assuming similarity means at least N items in common:

```
from itertools import combinations

# define minimum number of common items
N = 3

# aggregate as sets
s = df.groupby('type')['value'].agg(set)

# generate all combinations of sets
# and check is the intersection is at least N items
out = (pd.Series([len(a&b)>=N for a, b in combinations(s, 2)],
                 index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(combinations(s.index, 2)))
      )

# concat and add the reversed combinations (a/b -> b/a)
# we could have used a product in the first part but this
# would have required performing the computations twice
similarity = (
 pd.concat([out, out.swaplevel()])
   .loc[lambda x: x].reset_index(-1)
   .groupby(level=0)['level_1'].apply(lambda g: f"{g.name} is similar to {', '.join(g)}")
)

# update the first row of each group with the string
df.loc[~df['type'].duplicated(), 'similarity'] = df['type'].map(similarity)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   type  value               similarity
0     a      1  a is similar to b, c, d
1     a      2                      NaN
2     a      3                      NaN
3     a      4                      NaN
4     b      2     b is similar to d, a
5     b      3                      NaN
6     b      4                      NaN
7     b      5                      NaN
8     c      1        c is similar to a
9     c      3                      NaN
10    c      4                      NaN
11    d      2     d is similar to a, b
12    d      3                      NaN
13    d      4                      NaN
```

##### assuming similarity means one set is the subset of the other:

```
from itertools import combinations

s = df.groupby('type')['value'].agg(set)

out = (pd.Series([a.issubset(b) or b.issubset(a) for a, b in combinations(s, 2)],
                 index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(combinations(s.index, 2)))
      )

similarity = (
 pd.concat([out, out.swaplevel()])
   .loc[lambda x: x].reset_index(-1)
   .groupby(level=0)['level_1'].apply(lambda g: f"{g.name} is similar to {', '.join(g)}")
)

df.loc[~df['type'].duplicated(), 'similarity'] = df['type'].map(similarity)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   type  value            similarity
0     a      1  a is similar to c, d
1     a      2                   NaN
2     a      3                   NaN
3     a      4                   NaN
4     b      2     b is similar to d
5     b      3                   NaN
6     b      4                   NaN
7     b      5                   NaN
8     c      1     c is similar to a
9     c      3                   NaN
10    c      4                   NaN
11    d      2  d is similar to a, b
12    d      3                   NaN
13    d      4                   NaN
```

Comment: This is Magic Sir! You solved my problem Thank you so much!. Could I trouble you to explain your code to me in a simple way please? How would i go about editing this to know how many % it is similar (like how many values are matching to which type)

Comment: For the first code, change the value of `N` to define how many items in common you want. If you want a proportion, you need to incorporate the length of the sets in the calculation. For example `len(a&b)/max(len(a), len(b))>=0.2` for 20% of the longest

Comment: I also added comments to the code

Comment: Thank you very much for the further explanation! If I were to incorporate the length of the sets to get a proportion, Which portion of the code would i put that into?

Comment: Replacing `len(a&b)>=N` by `len(a&b)/max(len(a), len(b))>=0.2`

Comment: in your code, the variable has this portion of the code :

out = (pd.Series([a.issubset(b) or b.issubset(a) for a, b in combinations(s, 2)],
                 index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(combinations(s.index, 2)))

what is the 2 after 's' referring to?

Comment: Also what does Replacing len(a&b)>=N by len(a&b)/max(len(a), len(b))>=0.2 do exactly? does it search for values where at least 20% of the subset matches?

Comment: @hocuspocuslotus the `2` is because you want the combinations of 2 types (a/b or b/c for example. If you used `3` you would get a/b/c, a/b/d, etc.). The `len(a&b)/max(len(a), len(b))>=0.2` selects the groups for which the size of the intersection is at least 20% of the size of the longest of the two sets that are compared.

Comment: i see i understand the part about the `2`, but i still do not fully understand the portion on the intersection where you say that groups of the intersection are at least 20%.  Could you give me an example on it?

Comment: Example: `a = {1,2,3,4,5} ; b = {5, 6, 7} ; len(a&b)/max(len(a), len(b))` -> the intersection is `{5}`, so the ratio is `1/max(5, 3)` = `0.2`

Comment: that is really clear and easy to understand. Thanks for all your help mozway! Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
# Group all rows and transform as set
df1 = df.groupby('type', as_index=False)['value'].agg(set)

# Get all combinations
df1 = df1.merge(df1, how='cross').query('type_x != type_y')

# Compute the intersection between sets
df1['similarity'] = [row.value_x.intersection(row.value_y) 
                         for row in df1[['value_x', 'value_y']].itertuples()]

# Keep rows with at least 3 similarities then export report
sim = (df1.loc[df1['similarity'].str.len() >= 3].groupby('type_x')['type_y']
          .agg(', '.join).rename('similarity').rename_axis(index='type')
          .reset_index())
```

Output:

```
>>> sim
  type similarity
0    a    b, c, d
1    b       a, d
2    c          a
3    d       a, b
```

Comment: Quite clearer than the accepted answer but suffers from high memory cost -- any way to keep this clarity but scale for larger data sets?